# MySQL:set result two digits behind comma

Tags: mysql, count, digits

i have some formula:

```
CONCAT((SUM(X.lot_qty)-SUM(X.reject))/SUM(X.accept)*100,'%') AS Acceptance
```

but i get result like:

```
100.0000%
```

how to get result as 100.00%?

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to vote for answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the MySQL  [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function as:

```
CONCAT(ROUND((SUM(X.lot_qty)-SUM(X.reject))/SUM(X.accept)*100,2),'%') AS Acceptance
```